# Dart List<e> class questions

Tags: flutter, dart

for below print, both print results are the same. but is there a difference between `List<Dog> test = <Dog>[];` and `List<Dog> test2 =List<Dog>();`?

```
void main() {

  List<Dog> test = <Dog>[];
  List<Dog> test2 =List<Dog>();

  Dog dog = Dog(10);

  test.add(dog);
  print(test[0].age);

  test2.add(dog);
  print(test2[0].age);
}


class Dog {

  Dog({this.age});
  int age;

}
```

Comment: its the same, more people use `[]` however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no difference between the two. Both create a growable list as shown in the docs [here](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/List-class.html).

> The default growable list, as returned by new List() or [], keeps an internal buffer, and grows that buffer when necessary.This guarantees that a sequence of add operations will each execute in amortized constant time. Setting the length directly may take time proportional to the new length, and may change the internal capacity so that a following add operation will need to immediately increase the buffer capacity.

The one that is different from the above is if you wanted to create a non-growable list.

For that you would use,

```
List<Dog> fixedLengthList = new List(5);
```

In a fixed-length list, an error occurs when attempting to use operations that can change the length of the list.

Comment: This is a bad practice to specify the types of local variables. In Dart recommended to `AVOID type annotation initialized local variables`. This is not a good advice. https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-type-annotating-initialized-local-variables